# Performance Issue. ATI Catalyst Centre vs AMD Radeon Software

Tags: amd-radeon

Machine name : Acer ASpire ES 15
Specs : AMD A8-6410 quad core processor & Radeon R5 Graphics.
OS : Windows 10 64-bit

As far on the official site of Acer, it displays an old graphic driver (Catalyst ControlCentre) which was created 5 years ago. Performance is not that fast but not slow either. So I run a setup of updating the graphic driver from AMD website. It downloads a latest one (AMD Radeon Software).

However now the machine has slowed down more than ever and there are frequent lags while using mouse and all applications.

So is reverting back to 5 year old driver the only solution?

Comment: Did the slowing down occur immediately after installing the new Radeon software? Which Radeon version did you download? Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.4.1 ? Did you try slightly older versions as well? For instance: Adrenalin 2020 Edition 19.12.2 Recommended (WHQL). Also, which Radeon R5 graphics do you have exactly>?

Comment: Slowing did occur immediately after installing the new software. 
I installed the Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.4.1 & 20.5.1later as well. Its just laggy in both cases !

Which Radeon R5 graphics? I am entirely not sure about that.

Comment: Didn't realise it was just an integrated GPU. I would try downloading the 20.2.2, as that is the latest stable release. "Optional drivers" I would typically avoid. https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/apu/amd-series-processors/amd-a8-series-apu-for-laptops/a8-6410-radeon-r5-graphics